# vb.net / winform - ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

When my form loads, before the ComboBox has been populated and selected  this Event (SelectedIndexChanged) gets triggered. How can I prevent the code insides this Event from Executing before form has completely loaded? I tried testing for .SelectedIndex but it returns 0.

Comment: If SelectedIndex is 0 and not -1 then an item actually *did* get selected.  By your code, look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

in vb design/editor put `combobox enabled property` to `false` and then add after you load all to combobox `combobox1.enabled=true`

that will help!

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because as you add items to your combobox on startup it automatically selects the first in the list as the value to display (combobox default behavior). This default selection of the first item causes the selectedindexchanged handler to fire and your routine to run.

What you should do is look at using addhandler and removehandler.

For example:

your combobox index changed routine is called "indexchangedroutine" and your combobox is called "mycombobox".

On startup:

```
addhandler mycombobox.selectedindexchanged, addressof indexchangedroutine
```

the addressof portion is the name of the routine that you want called when this control's event fires.

To prevent the routine from firing on startup you should first fill your combobox items and second call addhandler to link the event and the logic.

In the event of needing to do an update (like an update timer) you can call removehandler instead of addhandler and it will disassociate the link between the logic and the control's event. You can do your update and when you are done addhandler can be called once again to link them back up for use.

Hope this helps you some. It may seem like there is more code involved but this method avoids using hacky fixes like "been here" flags in your selectedindexchanged routine.

Answer (score 0):

Do me.Validate.children did work